# Breakdance plugin issue: Unable to add third tab to the media library dialog while using WordPress page builder

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Breakdance plugin issue - it doesn't show up the 3rd tab in media library dialog

Currently I'm building a platform with a new page builder called Breakdance. It's at https://breakdance.com. And you can download a free version of the open-source plugin and upload to your admin panel to see how it works.

The problem is, when I open up the media library dialog you may have noticed that there are 2 horizontal tabs by default(Upload Image & Media Library) and currently I need to add a new one but still unable.

This problem raises only when I edit my page with breakdance. And of course, I am able to add the tab by extending wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Select when I edit my page on the default editor. Just like the below JavaScript code:

```
var old_media_frame_select = wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Select;
    var types = [];

wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Select = old_media_frame_select.extend({

// Tab / Router
// https://atimmer.github.io/wordpress-jsdoc/media_views_frame_select.js.html#sunlight-1-line-113
   browseRouter: function browseRouter(routerView) {
      old_media_frame_select.prototype.browseRouter.apply(this, arguments);

        // Bit dirty, but elementor dont set the types allowed in the popup
        if (document.querySelector('.elementor-control-image')) {
            types = ['image'];
        } else {
            types = this.options.library.type;
        }

        routerView.set({
            newTab: {
                text: 'ThirdTab',
                   priority: 45
            }
        });
    },

    // Handlers
    bindHandlers: function bindHandlers() {
        old_media_frame_select.prototype.bindHandlers.apply( this, arguments );
        this.on( 'content:create:newTab', this.frameContent, this );
    },

    /**
     * Render callback for the content region in the `browse` mode.
     *
     * @param {wp.media.controller.Region} contentRegion
     */
    frameContent: function frameContent(contentRegion) {
        var state = this.state();
        setTimeout(function() {
          newMediaTab(state);
        }, 200)
    },

    getFrame: function getFrame(id) {
        return this.states.findWhere({ id: id });
    }
});
```

I was planning to make an addon plugin to make it work but as it didn't work correctly so I even tried modifying wpuiforbuilder/media.js and extending the old media frame just like the above but the error still persists.

If you are a wordpress plugin developer, do you mind giving me some helpful advices?
Thank you!
Olex

Comment: Try the Breakdance community on Facebook? https://www.facebook.com/groups/5118076864894234